# how to extract field from JSON that return two string withing the same JSON

Tags: java, json, string

I have JSON looks like this

```
{
    "description":
    {
        "html": "A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the scripting engine handles objects in memory in Microsoft Edge. ...",
        "text": "<p>A remote code execution vulnerability exists in the way that the scripting engine handles objects in memory in Microsoft Edge. ...</p>"
    }
}
```

I extract the field description but it contains both html and text, while I'm only interesting in text field.

```
while (true)
{
    //Read
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String lines = null;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(lines);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    result = stringBuilder.toString();

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) parser.parse(result);
    if(methodType == MethodType.Retrieve_Vulnerability_info)
    {
        String scan_vuln_title= json2.get("title").toString();
        String scan_vuln_severityScore = json2.get("severityScore").toString();
        String scan_vuln_publishe_date = json2.get("published").toString();
        String scan_vuln_description = json2.get("description").toString();
        splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setSeverityScore(scan_vuln_severityScore);
        splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setVulnerability_title(scan_vuln_title);
        splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setPublished_date(scan_vuln_publishe_date);
        splunkdata.getScan().getList_of_found_Vulnerabilties().get(Vulnerability_id).setDescription(scan_vuln_description);
        System.out.print("\n Rapid7 : Successful GET, vulnerabilities info of : "+ scan_vuln_title + " were retrieved" );
    }
```

Is there a way how to extract text content only?

Comment: Well, since it is nested json something like `json2.get("description").get("text")` should do the trick (assuming `json2` repesents a map, JsonObject etc.) - you might need to add some parsing and some null checks but I'll leave that for you.

Comment: What is the type of `json2`? There are many different JSON parsers/libraries which provide different API so answer will depend on what you are using.

Comment: I'm using SimpleJSON library, I have added the full code, I don't have the mond get("text")

Comment: Aside from main question: it seems that your `text` and `html` are flipped, since `text` contains `<p>...</p>` structure while `html` contains only "rendered" data.

Comment: this is returned from the Server side - I think they are flipped as well

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extracting to a String, extract the description as a JSON object.
so what your code would look like is this,

```
JSONObject json3 = json2.getJSONObject("description")
```

then,

```
String html = json3.get("html")
String text = json3.get("text")
```

Also, a quick reminder, I'm using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Edit1: Since you are using simple.json

```
JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) object.get("description");
String html = (String) json2.get("html");
String text = (String) json2.get("text");
```

Comment: JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject) object.get("description"); , object is not known.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use JsonPath [click here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to know more with working example.

Comment: I don't want to use another library!